# PCA regression worse than non-PCA under multicollinearity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, pca

I have two questions regarding multicollinearity.

I'm trying to perform a multiple linear regression under a dataset where variables are high correlated and normally distributed. To get rid of the multicollinearity I first performed PCA on the dataset (explaining 95% of the variance) and after that I calculated the regression. I also calculated the regression without PCA in order to compare both.

The RSME of the PCA regression is higher than de RSME of the non-PCA regression and I can't understand why it is happening.

1 - In my view, after performing PCA, the RSME should be smaller, right? Can anyone give some insights/explanations about that?

2 - As I said, the dataset is high correlated and it also has identical variables in it (yes, identical!). What should I do in this situation? Is it better to delete the identical variables or perform PCA? P.S.: it has identical variables because it comes from an assignment and probably the professor expects that we further investigate this and manage to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Multicollinearity has no effect on the raw performance of linear regression. It only inflates the standard errors on the coefficients. Therefore, you shouldn't expect RSME to be smaller after performing PCA. PCA necessarily removes information from the input data, so in fact you should expect the RSME to increase as a result.

Comment: (+1) But of course the *test-set* error can be lower for PCA regression (because it provides some regularization).